# How can I reliably transpose an array of chars to an array of uint64_t and back again

Tags: c, arrays, encryption, byte

I have a class project coding DES and am having problems obtaining 64 bits blocks from the input file.

Everything works fine in the encryption phase, but when I get to decrypting, after reading my file into a buffer, my CharArrayToInt64() function replaces large portions of the input buffer with F.

Here's my function:

```
    void charArrayToInt64(uint64_t *bufferText, char *buffer, long length){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < length/8 + 1; i++){
            bufferText[i] = 0x0;
            bufferText[i] = ((uint64_t)buffer[i*8]<<56)
                            | ((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 1]<<48)
                            | ((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 2]<<40)
                            | ((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 3]<<32)
                            | ((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 4]<<24)
                            | ((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 5]<<16)
                            | ((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 6]<<8)
                            | ((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 7]);
        }
    }
```

This is the output of the buffer, and the array of uint64_t in the encryption phase:

```
    Buffer:                              uint64_t array:
    5468 6973 2069 7320                  5468 6973 2069 7320
    6120 7465 7874 2066                  6120 7465 7874 2066
    696c 6520 7772 6974                  696c 6520 7772 6974
    7465 6e20 666f 7220                  7465 6e20 666f 7220
    7465 7374 2070 7572                  7465 7374 2070 7572
    706f 7365 732e 2049                  706f 7365 732e 2049
    6620 4445 5320 776f                  6620 4445 5320 776f
    726b 7320 636f 7272                  726b 7320 636f 7272
    6563 746c 792c 2061                  6563 746c 792c 2061
    6e64 2074 6865 2066                  6e64 2074 6865 2066
    696c 6520 6973 2072                  696c 6520 6973 2072
    6561 6420 616e 6420                  6561 6420 616e 6420
    7370 6c69 7420 7072                  7370 6c69 7420 7072
    6f70 6572 6c79 2c20                  6f70 6572 6c79 2c20
    7468 6973 2074 6578                  7468 6973 2074 6578
    7420 7368 6f75 6c64                  7420 7368 6f75 6c64
    2072 6574 7572 6e20                  2072 6574 7572 6e20
    7265 6164 6162 6c65                  7265 6164 6162 6c65
    2efc                                 ffff ffff fd7f 0000
```

Following is the output of the buffer and uint64_t array during the decryption phase (note that they will not match the above as I'm using the previously encrypted text):

```
    Buffer:                              uint64_t array:
    e824 8aa4 db58 5b12                  ffff ffff db58 5b12
    b8d2 2b8f 980c 915f                  ffff ffff ffff 915f
    f942 a226 9c69 bcc4                  ffff ffff ffff ffc4
    c660 bd78 179d b628                  ffff ffff ffff b628
    1ed1 d846 ceb1 f8b5                  ffff ffff ffff ffb5
    2e67 fa25 66bd 0f13                  ffff ffff ffbd 0f13
    d11d 1203 d10f dc9e                  ffff ffff ffff ff9e
    6124 0cf1 9393 3816                  ffff ffff ff93 3816
    efab b9ad fb20 23c0                  ffff ffff ffff ffc0
    6a2a 20c1 a610 1422                  ffff ffff a610 1422
    119d d9c5 9de1 0f08                  ffff ffff ffe1 0f08
    331e d4e7 2214 bdb1                  ffff ffff ffff ffb1
    c408 74e2 6e14 84e6                  ffff ffff ffff ffe6
    3fe6 5eca 04c5 70c6                  ffff ffff ffff ffc6
    12f8 bcaa 1df7 342d                  ffff ffff fff7 342d
    93eb 15d8 eb8d b51e                  ffff ffff ffff b51e
    7fd2 a2d7 b357 a6eb                  ffff ffff ffff ffeb
    7fb9 bf2b 0ebe bb99                  ffff ffff ffff ff99
    3300                                 3300 0000 0000 0000
```

As you can see, in the encryption phase, my function messes up only the last line, and in the decryption phase the exact same function messes up all bu the very last line...

Any help would be very much appreciated as I've spent the past several hours trying to figure this one out to no avail.

If you need/want any extra info, I'll do my best to provide it.

---

<strike>EDIT-1: With help from @coderredoc, @chux and @Myst my problem has been mostly solved, and the code is much cleaner aswell! (previous function `charArrayToInt64()` no longer used)</strike>

One issue remains: that is if the last 64bit bloc in `bufferText` is not filled completely by `fread()` I end up with trailing bits that i can't seem to get rid of (even if i set the full block to 0 before filling it). This causes problems during the decryption phase:

Original input file:

> This is a text file written for test purposes. If DES works correctly, and the file is read and split properly, this text should return readable and with no errors.

Decrypted output with trailing 'random' bits:

> This is a text file written for test purposes. If DES works correctly, and the file is read and split properly, this text should return readable and with no errÒÕäTR†

I've tried:
 `memset(bufferText, 0, length + 8);` (aswell as variations of the last parameter)
`bufferText[length/8] =  bufferText[length/8]<<((length%8)*8);` (aswell as shifting them back into original position after)

---

EDIT-2

Previous edit is obsolete, turns out I skipped a part of my assignment which required me to read one byte at a time which in turn required the use of `fgetc()` and `fputc()` for reading and writing. All answers remain very helpful and on point though so thanks a bunch!

Comment: Why the last lines are incomplete? Can you provide the full line?

Comment: How  large are `bufferText` and `buffer` and how is the hopefully unused part of `buffer` initialised?

Comment: @coderredoc if you're talking about the last lines in buffer, they're not incomplete, the rest is all 0's

@alk `bufferText` and `buffer` are respectively `length/8 + 1` and `length + 1` long with `length = ftell(ptrR)` (after executing `fseek(ptrR, 0, SEEK_END)`)

Comment: sry for the double post, my pc refused to let me edit previous comment again for extra precision:
@alk considering `buffer` is created at the exact size it needs to be for the given file, there shouldn't be an unused part, `bufferText` on the other hand does have an unused part but as they are both variable-length depending on the file size i did not specifically initialize bufferText (`fread(buffer, length, 1, ptrR);` is the only definition of buffer)

Comment: First of all we are talking about the second conversion from `Buffer` to `uint64_t` array. isn't it? And `buffer` contains left columns data and `buFFertext` will contain the formed array. And buffer conatins on each position `e8`,`24`, etc. Each bytes. Clarify this. Confirm if I get it correct.

Comment: @coderredoc yes that is correct, so basically the formed array should be identical to buffer except the last line which should be completed with 0s to fill the remaining bytes that do not exist in buffer

Comment: `((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 1]<<48)` --> `((uint64_t)(unsigned char)buffer[i*8 + 1]<<48)`  Convert `char` to `unsigned char` before widening it to `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer I will address the actual question:

> having problems obtaining 64 bits blocks from the input file

...rather than the one addressed so far:

> > after reading my file into a buffer, my CharArrayToInt64() function replaces large portions of the input buffer with F.

I recommend (IMHO) that you **read the file directly into a `uint64_t` array / buffer**, rather than copy the data from a byte array.

While an `unsigned char` array you might encounter memory alignment concerns, a `uint64_t` array is guaranteed to be correctly memory aligned and you only need to worry about padding...

...Oh, and please use the `unsigned` versions, as indicated by others on this thread, this is what's causing the shifting issues.

Once both arrays (encryption and decryption) use the same unsigned type, your code will look much cleaner.

Good luck.

Comment: Agree with all except "might expose endian-ness concerns".  It is likely that that after reading the 64-bits of data in _some_ endian, that 64-bit  packet may need an endian adjustment for further `uint64_t` processing.  IAC, reading it into a `uint64_t` to begin with is a very good idea for the other reasons mentioned and any endian adjustment could be done in place.

Comment: @Myst I'll give this a try, i used an `unsigned char *buffer` followed by the conversion because every single example of `fread()` i found over the course of my morning specifically said to use `unsigned char` so i assumed that was the only way, I guess I should have looked at the documentation directly instead!

Comment: @chux - thanks, I removed the part about endian concerns since you're probably right. However, I found that some computations allow endianness to cancel out as data moves in and out of a numerical object.

Comment: @Chris, an `uint64_t` array can be safely casted to a `char *` pointer... but the reverse isn't true due to memory alignment concerns.

Comment: @myst [True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025621/how-can-i-reliably-transpose-an-array-of-chars-to-an-array-of-uint64-t-and-back/48026982?noredirect=1#comment83024090_48026982) - if the endian of the data matches the processors endian, the endian adjustment if a no-op.  (very fast those no-ops)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your case `char` is signed (this is implementation defined - char is signed by default in your machine) - so when shifted it is getting signextended for characters that are having MSB `1`. Resulting in series of `ff`'s to the left of the number.

For example if we extend `0x24` to all these shifts it will be

```
2400000000000000
24000000000000
240000000000
2400000000
24000000
240000
2400
24
```

For `0xe8` the same would be

```
e800000000000000
ffe8000000000000
ffffe80000000000
ffffffe800000000
ffffffffe8000000
ffffffffffe80000
ffffffffffffe800
ffffffffffffffe8
```

Now think of this, when you `OR` this with others the `ff`'s win and all the bits are set. And you see `ff`'s.

Correct solution in your case would be

```
  bufferText[i]  = (((uint64_t)buffer[i*8]<<56) & (uint64_t)0xff<<56)
                                | (((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 1]<<48) & (uint64_t)0xff<<48)
                                | (((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 2]<<40) & (uint64_t)0xff<<40)
                                | (((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 3]<<32) & (uint64_t)0xff<<32)
                                | (((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 4]<<24) & (uint64_t)0xff<<24)
                                | (((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 5]<<16) & (uint64_t)0xff<<16)
                                | (((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 6]<<8) & (uint64_t)0xff<<8)
                                | (((uint64_t)buffer[i*8 + 7]) & (uint64_t)0xff<<0);
```

As mentioned by **chux** there is a cleaner solution using the `unsigned char` typecast which will be something like

```
 bufferText[i] = ((uint64_t)(unsigned char)buffer[i*8]<<56) |
                  ...
```

---

Edit-1

If you have already declared the char buffer type as `unsigned` you don't need to `void charArrayToInt64(uint64_t *bufferText, char *buffer, long length){` rather in the function explicity mention that it's a `unsigned char` buffer

```
void charArrayToInt64(uint64_t *bufferText,unsigned char *buffer, long length){ ...
```

Then the explicit cast is not needed. And you will be doing fine with your original method.

---

Using `memset` you can zero out whole buffer.Check the function out. Also if you are talking in context of using `bufferText[i] = 0x0;` then more logically you don't even need to initialize it with `0` because after all you are setting it the very next time. That's why you can even remove this line from the code `bufferText[i] = 0x0;` and also another thing instead of using `long` length it is better to use `size_t` which goes with use that you have with `length`.

Comment: thank you so much!! There was no way i would have found this myself seeing as in my main i declared the buffer as `unsigned char buffer` so i didn't even think to look in the function declaration!! one extra quick question: to initialize `bufferText` with all 0s is there a faster way than to loop over it considering it's a variable-size array?

Comment: @Chris.: `memset` is the way.

Comment: @Chris If `buffer` in `main` was `unsigned char buffer`, why code `charArrayToInt64()` using `char *buffer`?  Instead, code with `void charArrayToInt64(uint64_t *bufferText, unsigned char *buffer, long length)` and avoid the `(unsigned char)` cast.

Comment: @chux.: It seems OP forgot to check how he declared it. Otherwise the problem wouldn't have arised.

Comment: @chux.: I see..you are saying as we are setting it why get the hassle of initilaizing it with `0`? yep right

Comment: @chux like @coderredoc said, i wasn't paying attention when i wrote `charArrayToInt64()` and wrote `char *buffer` instead of ùnsigned char *buffer`

@coderredoc thanks, i meantzero out the whole buffer before calling the function, as i assume the end of the last line being random bits instead of 0s is due to the fact i never initialized it, as for the `long length` once again i wasn't thinking straight while coding that bit, `size_t` is definitely the better solution